# How to search for the word in each line of a file and print the next value of it in python

Tags: python

I want to search for the word in the file and print next value of it using any way using python

Following is the code :

```
def matchTest(testsuite, testList):

  hashfile = open("/auto/file.txt", 'a')

  with open (testsuite, 'r') as suite:
      for line in suite:
          remove_comment=line.split('#')[0]
          for test in testList:
              if re.search(test, remove_comment, re.IGNORECASE):
                  hashfile.writelines(remove_comment)
                  search_word=remove_comment.split(':component=>"', maxsplit=1)[-1].split(maxsplit=1)
                  print(search_word)
  hashfile.close()
```

`remove_comment` has the following lines:

```
{:component=>"Cloud Tier Mgmt", :script=>"b.py", :testname=>"c", --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG --config_file=a.yaml"}

{:skipfilesyscheck=>1, :component=>"Content Store", :script=>"b.py", --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG --config_file=a.yaml -s"}

{:script=>"b.py", :params=>"--ddrs=$DDRS --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG --config_file=a.yaml", :numddr=>1, :timeout=>10000, :component=>"Cloud-Connectivity" }
```

So now I want the output to be only the compnent value as following:

```
Cloud Tier Mgmt

Content Store

Cloud-Connectivity
```

Please anyone help

Comment: What is the contents of testList?

Comment: testList has the list of testcase name. 

['a' , 'b']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def matchTest(testsuite, testList):
    hashfile = open("hash.txt", 'a')
    with open ('text.txt', 'r') as suite:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in suite.readlines() if line.strip()]
        print(lines)
        for line in lines:
            f = re.search(r'component=>"(.*?)"', line)  # find part you need
            hashfile.write(f.group(1)+'\n')
    hashfile.close()
```

**Output written to file:**

```
Cloud Tier Mgmt
Content Store
Cloud-Connectivity
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the rest of the code is correct (we can't see what regular expressions you are using), you need to change only one line to:

```
search_word = remove_comment.split(':component=>"', maxsplit=1)[-1].split('"', maxsplit=1)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
def get_component(file_path):
word_list = []
file = open(file_path, 'r')
i = 0;
for line in file:
    for word in line.split(','):
        word = word[1:]
        if word.startswith(":component=>"):
            word = word[13:-1]
            word_list.append(word)
            print(word)
            return word_list
```

You can copy-paste and give file_path it going to work well.

here is my output:

```
['Cloud Tier Mgmt', 'Content Store', 'Cloud-Connectivity ']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

remove_comment = '''{:component=>"Cloud Tier Mgmt", :script=>"b.py", :testname=>"c", --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG --config_file=a.yaml"}

{:skipfilesyscheck=>1, :component=>"Content Store", :script=>"b.py", --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG --config_file=a.yaml -s"}

{:script=>"b.py", :params=>"--ddrs=$DDRS --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG --config_file=a.yaml", :numddr=>1, :timeout=>10000, :component=>"Cloud-Connectivity" }'''

data = [x.split('"')[1] for x in re.findall(r'component=>[^,:}]*', remove_comment)]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
['Cloud Tier Mgmt', 'Content Store', 'Cloud-Connectivity']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
def matchTest(testsuite, testList):
    hashfile = open("/auto/file.txt", 'a')

    with open (testsuite, 'r') as suite:
      for line in suite.split("\n"):
        remove_comment=line.split('#')[0]
        for i in remove_comment.split(","):
            if "component=>" in i:
                search_word = re.search("\"(.*)\"", i).group(1)
                print(search_word)
    hashfile.close()
```

Output

```
Cloud Tier Mgmt
Content Store
Cloud-Connectivity
```